# Printing a substring, if the string contains information given from scanner input. (Java)

Tags: java

Here is what I have:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an uppercase letter: ");
    String Letter = input.next();

    String LettersTwo = "A" + "B" + "C";
    String DigitTwo = LettersTwo.substring(0) + "2";

    String LettersThree = "D" + "E" + "F";
    String DigitThree = LettersThree.substring(0) + "3";

    String LettersFour = "G" + "H" + "I";
    String DigitFour = LettersFour.substring(0) + "4";

    String LettersFive = "J" + "K" + "L";
    String DigitFive = LettersFive.substring(0) + "5";

    String LettersSix = "M" + "N" + "O";
    String DigitSix = LettersSix.substring(0) + "6";

    String LettersSeven = "P" + "Q" + "R" + "S";
    String DigitSeven = LettersSeven.substring(0) + "7";

    String LettersEight = "T" + "U" + "V";
    String DigitEight = LettersEight.substring(0) + "8";

    String LettersNine = "W" + "X" + "Y" + "Z";
    String DigitNine = LettersNine.substring(0) + "9";

    if (Letter.contains(LettersTwo)) {
        System.out.println("The corresponding digit is " + DigitTwo);

    }
```

If the user inputs an uppercase letter of A, B, or C, I want the system to print out, "The corresponding number is 2". I correlated the number to the uppercase letter in substrings. The system isn't printing that out and what I have it as is if Letter contains something from LettersTwo, then to print that out. I am new to programming though so I don't know if I have that written correctly. Can someone help me get this working?

Comment: `String LettersTwo = "A" + "B" + "C";` is a lot more typing than `String LettersTwo = "ABC";` and produces the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take another look at your `if` statement:

```
if (Letter.contains(LettersTwo))
```

Here you're checking to see if a single letter contains a string of letters. Logically that'll return `false`. But if you use it this way:

```
if (LettersTwo.contains(Letter))
```

You're checking if a group of letters contains a single letter.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that's how I had it. I guess when you're new this is what will happen.

Comment: No problem. Everyone starts somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious approach is to use an `if` statement or `switch` statement. Anther approach, which seems to be what you are trying to do, is to use an array of `String`. (Note that when you start adding numbers to the end of a variable name, this is a strong indication that you should use an array.) If you want to get fancy, you can turn this into a lookup table with a `Map<Character, Integer>`.

You should also look at the documentation for `String.contains()`. It doesn't work the way you are trying to use it.